# Como preencher corretamente as linhas e colunas utilizando React datasheet?

Tags: javascript, react, formatação, react-hooks

Estou usando o `react datasheet` para exportar e importar dados colando em minhas tabelas da aplicação. Espero que todas as colunas e linhas que eu copiar sejam coladas normalmente. Porém, só uma linha e duas colunas estão sendo preenchidas. Tentei utilizar o `parsePaste` também, mas não consigo resolver esse problema com ele.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
return (
    <Datasheet
      data={grid}
      loading={loading}
      title="Impostos"
      valueRenderer={cell => cell.value}
      onContextMenu={(e, cell) => (cell.readOnly ? e.preventDefault() : null)}
      onCellsChanged={changes => {
        changes.forEach(({ row, col, value }) => {
          grid[row][col] = { ...grid[row][col], value };
        });

        const gridWithoutEmptyRows = grid.filter(rowHasValues);
        if (lastRowHasAnyValue(gridWithoutEmptyRows)) {
          pushNewLineToEnd(gridWithoutEmptyRows, {
            [originColumn]: {
              value: '',
              dataEditor: Selector,
              valueViewer: ValueViewer,
            },
          });
        }
        setGrid(gridWithoutEmptyRows);

        const dataFromGrid = gridWithoutEmptyRows.slice(1);
        dispatch(setTaxes(mapGridToTaxes(dataFromGrid)));
      }}
      parsePaste={strings => {
        const rows = strings.split('\n\r');
        const table = rows.map(row => {
          return row.split('');
        });
        debugger;

        return table;
      }}
    />   );
};
```

Todas as linhas e colunas devem ser preenchidas, mas o que estou recebendo é isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o que era pra aparecer ...

Comment: @novic todas as colunas e linhas deveriam ser preenchidas porque eu copiei tres colunas e tres linhas de uma planilha de excel